# To get date & time in python

Tags: python

How to get the current date with zero hours in python?

When i am trying datetime.datetime.now() it is showing current date & time but i would like to get current date with zero hours.

Comment: When you say zero hours do you mean exclusively remove just the hours section? I'm assuming you mean you just want the year month day. Since removing just hours with minutes and seconds would be odd. In which case you could just use `datetime.date.today()`?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now().date()`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use strftime to format the time as follows, this will give you the 'time' without the hours, minutes etc:

```
    timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d"
    time_now = time.strftime(time.time())
```

Alternatively, if you want todays date, without a time aspect, use this from datetime

```
    from datetime import date
    today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M")
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try the following code if you don't want to show hours in your code:
`print str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + " "+str(datetime.datetime.now().minute) + ":" + str(datetime.datetime.now().second)`